# Prevent NUnit tests to run depending on environment

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, nunit

I'm struggle with this one quite a long time now. Some background: I created my automated test framework using Selenium. With one project being pure NUnit tests and second one that does all the work for the tests. Now, in test project I keep the directories to all environments I run my tests against. So far many of my tests were read-only and didn't bother much about if tests did not run on environment that they supposed to. This has changed as I started to run some 'write' tests.

I need to prevent this 'Write' tests to run on any other environment then localhost. So far I tried to use method attributes and getting test method names on run time and do work then but this is not quite efficient. Can you guys point me a good solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit have [category](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2.10) attribute. 
You can group tests by categories and run only wanted categories.

Comment: I think I was looking at this attribute before, however, this groups tests to a categories, but still if I forget to change URL (in app.config) that points to lets say QA environment it will still run this tests. But I might be wrong...

Comment: @Jakubee You are configuring for any environment separate test configurations, and each configuration includes a selected group of tests. If you do not change the app.config nothing will happen because this group of tests did not perform.

Answer (score 3):

I would tag the tests to exclude with a particular category name then define a SetUp function which will stop the tests from running if they are tagged with that name and if you are on a particular environment such as Production. Place the SetUp function in a BaseClass and have all your test fixtures inherit it. The SetUp function will run before every test and prevent it from running if it needs to.

Something like this:

```
public class BaseSetup
{
        protected const string CategoryToExclude = "Write";

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {  
            string env =  ConfigurationManager.GetEnvironment();
            if ( env == Constants.Environments.PROD && (TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Categories"].Contains(CategoryToExclude)))
            {
                Assert.Inconclusive(String.Format("Cannot run this test on environment: {0}", env));
            }
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTests : BaseSetup
    {
        [Test]
        [Category(CategoryToExclude)]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestMethod1");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestMethod2");  
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer is almost the same I ended up with. I will up vote it as this is more detailed and correct answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for my first upvote @Jakubee! I'd also like to mention that TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Categories"] doesn't work in all versions of NUnit as they are still experimenting with it... in which case maybe I would superfix the name of the test with the category and then use TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name.Contains(CategoryToExclude).